# Деление DWORD на 10

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Как работает алгоритм `Div10` в этой программе? Непонятен математический смысл всех этих обменов при помощи `xchg`.

```
; DWToAscii преобразует 4-байтовое число в последовательность символов
DWToAscii proc near
    call Div10
    mov si, dx
    or si, ax
    jz done         ; Записать первую цифру
    push bx     
    call DWToAscii
    pop bx          ; Достать очередную цифру
done:
    add bl, '0'     ; Перевести цифру в символ
    mov [di], bl    ; Сохранить символ
    inc di
    ret
DWToAscii endp

Div10 proc near
    mov cx, 10
    mov bx, ax
    xchg ax, dx
    xor dx, dx
    div cx
    xchg dx, bx
    ret
Div10 endp
```

Мы делим четырехбайтовое число в `dx:ax` на 10. Во второй строке сохраняем младшие биты в `bx`, вместо младших битов загружаем старшие, одновременно сохраняя их в `dx` (уже это непонятно: зачем сохранять их, если мы уже их сохранили?). Обнуляем старшие биты. Делим на 10 число `0:ax`, где в `ax` сейчас старшие биты. Теперь в `ax` - частное, а в `dx` - остаток, и остаток мы заменяем младшими битами числа. Мы как-то разорвали число, но почему-то это не повлияло на результат. Это удивительно, ведь разложение числа по основанию системы счисления не позволяет как попало оперировать его частями.

Вызов функции:

```
start:
    mov dx, 12345   ; Старшие биты
    mov ax, 6789    ; Младшие биты
    mov cx, 10
    mov di, offset digit

    call DWToAscii

    mov [di], byte ptr 0Dh
    inc di
    mov [di], byte ptr 0Ah
    inc di
    mov [di], byte ptr '$'
    mov dx, offset digit
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не бред, это работает. Здесь третья форма инструкции div - она делит двойное слово, записанное в регистрах dx:ax, на число в cx. Так работает div. Добавил код в пост.

Comment: Делимое передается в двух регистрах dx:ax. Это задача из книги - надо реализовать на 16-битном асме вывод 4-байтового числа в виде последовательности символов. Для этого используется стек и вспомогательная функция деления на 10.

Comment: Да, это опечатка.

Comment: Вы что то не договариваете. Я бы не стал функцию переводящую в десятичную систему 4 байта, называть `DWToAscii`, потому как `DW` означает 2 (_два_) байта. И перед ее вызовом в пару dx:ax грузят обратите внимание десятичное число кусками, т.е. если бы это было 4х байтовое двоичное значение, то оно выглядело бы совсем по другому. У меня подозрение что в книге предполагалось два раза вызвать DWToAscci для перевода старшей и младшей частей

Comment: @Mike, dw обозначает два байта только если это директива Define Word. А когда это входит в название функции или переменной, то это вполне себе Double Word (4 байта).

Comment: @insolor Но только с нормальным четырехбайтным числом она работать не умеет. ей готовят разбитое по правилам десятичной системы счисления число кусками. Ибо 123456789 десятичное в нормальном четырехбайтном виде должно было бы выглядеть как hex 75BCD15 что двухбайтовыми частями в десятичной системе 1883:52501

Comment: @Mike, на самом деле, можно реализовать процедуру, которая будет с двумя частями числа, разбитыми по границам десятичных разрядов, но процедура из вопроса явно так делать не умеет: [результат выполнения](http://i.imgur.com/CEAokkR.png)

Comment: @insolor Да, можно. но это как то странно, потому как четырехбайтовое число хранить разбитым по десятичным разрядам не принято. хотя конечно можно предположить, что число изначально было в BCD и его двухбайтные части отдельно перевели в двоичное. А вообще тут что то архистранное или я чего то не вижу. Дело в том, что первый div10 поделит 12345(который пришел в dx) на 10 и вернет bx=5, ax=1234, dx=6789. после чего 5 кладем в стек, делим 6789 на 10, кладем 9 в стек. dx=1234, ax=678 и так далее, т.е. dx и ax меняются местами и в стек ложатся по очереди цифры из разных частей

Comment: @Mike, у меня подозрение, что процедура Div10 (или обе процедуры) вообще не работает как задумано. Даже если делать деление на 16 и в качестве аргументов использовать 1234h и 5678h, в результате будет какой-то мусор (т.е. совсем не те числа).

Comment: Обновил пост, добавил книги из предыдущих глав. Когда я разбирал этот алгоритм, мне оказалось непонятно, почему это математически корректно.

Comment: Точно, похоже на [BCD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Comment: @typemoon А что общего у текста в книге и вашем примере ? у них две операции деления, они переносят остаток от деления старшей части в младший разряд для последующей работы. А в вашем 16 битном варианте происходит одно единственное деление, разряд никуда не переносится и куски числа то из старшей то из младшей части кладутся в стек, откуда готовятся к печати в обратном порядке