# Деление без DIV... и без MUL

Tags: ассемблер, деление

Нужно произвести деление на 10 без DIV (IDIV) и без MUL (IMUL). И без FPU/SSE, естественно...
Как это можно сделать?
p.s. Причём, так, чтобы остаток тоже был. Хотя, его можно разницей вычислить.

Comment: Вычитание из исходного числа 10 в цикле не пойдет?

Comment: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH09/CH09-6.html

Comment: @Arhad, там деление через умножение. Хотя можно конечно извратиться и сделать умножение на 6554 через lea, но это как-то слишком по-моему)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: «[Деление DWORD на 10](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494739/208074)».

Comment: @Arhad, ага, помню тот вопрос, там пример и снимок из книги не имеют между собой ничего общего.

Comment: В ответе на вопрос «[Деление заменить смещением (сдвигом)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545838/208074)» @Harry приводит [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545838/208074) деления на 10.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Деление заменить смещением(сдвигом)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545769/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc)